# Is there a way to replace TOP 100 PERCENT from this Rank() OVER SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So this SQL orders pages in a photo book, it is called after newly uploaded pages are added, it updates the sequence order:

```
UPDATE Gallery.AlbumAsset
SET
    Sequence = X.Rank
FROM Gallery.AlbumAsset albass
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
        Rank() OVER (Order By Sequence, AssetId) As Rank, AssetId
    FROM Gallery.AlbumAsset
    WHERE AlbumId = @AlbumId and Sequence > 0
    ORDER BY Rank

) X ON albass.AssetId = X.AssetId AND albass.Sequence != X.Rank
WHERE albass.AlbumId = @AlbumId
```

I think the TOP 100 PERCENT is confusing and not optimal for readability, so I attempted the change:

```
UPDATE Gallery.AlbumAsset
SET
    Sequence = X.Rank
FROM Gallery.AlbumAsset albass
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        Rank() OVER (Order By Sequence, AssetId) As Rank, AssetId
    FROM Gallery.AlbumAsset
    WHERE AlbumId = @AlbumId and Sequence > 0
    ORDER BY Rank

) X ON albass.AssetId = X.AssetId AND albass.Sequence != X.Rank
WHERE albass.AlbumId = @AlbumId
```

Which causes the error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Perhaps I just need to use `TOP` but I was trying to simplify this SQL a bit but its been a while since I have worked with "more complex" SQL statements, I almost tried to use CROSS APPLY somehow but I think that is an incorrect choice in direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove both the TOP and ORDER BY clauses from the subquery - since this is a subquery, the ORDER BY clause serves no purpose and I suspect the TOP clause is only there to prevent the error you are seeing regarding using ORDER by in a subquery.

Comment: So I am not familiar with Rank(), is Rank() Over (Order By Sequence, AssetId) going to potentially return a different Rank number than Rank() Over(Order By Sequence)? I am assuming part of refreshing the sequence was including the AssetId order as that is the Primary Key Increment by One and so can give you a sense of order based on insertion

Comment: @BrianOgden, Nathan is saying remove `ORDER BY RANK`, fourth line from the bottom. Not to change the `ORDER BY` in `RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ....`

Comment: Yes I know, I was slipping in an additional question there, I thought of the question of thinking about removing ORDER BY Rank because the only Order by removing ORDER By Rank is Order By Sequence, AssetId, but sometimes two records have the same Sequence, say "5" and I was thinking that this could potential mess up the SQL, I am testing some potentials right now

Comment: Have the same Sequence number does not cause any issues with @Nathan's recommended changes

Comment: In answer to your question, yes, putting a different set of columns on the `Over` part will potentially lead to different `Rank` results.

Comment: @BrianOgden when using RANK() the ORDER BY clause inside the OVER clause is what is used to sort the data and determine the rank value, this is separate to the ORDER BY clause of the overall SELECT statement, which determines the order in which rows are returned. Note that with RANK it is possible for two or more rows to receive the *same rank value*.  If you need a unique sequential number to to be generated then you could use ROW_NUMBER instead.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, yes I see that RANK() has the potential to return the same rank value, since the ORDER BY in OVER is "ORDER BY Sequence, AssetId" and AssetId is always a unique key I will not have this problem with RANK() it seems, I tested two records having the same Sequence = 5 and different AssetIds: AssetId = 1, AssetId = 2 and Rank returned unique sequential numbers

Comment: Yes that's correct, as long as you never have two rows with the same value for Sequence and AssetId the Rank() value will be unique. However if that's what you actually want then ROW_NUMBER will do the same thing but is guaranteed never to return duplicate values, so could be more robust for your purpose.